# Where the Magnetic moment and angular momentum relation is valid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, rotational-dynamics, magnetic-moment

There is a relation between angular momentum and magnetic moment as

$$M/L = q/2m $$

where $M$ is magnetic moment and $L$ is angular momentum. So this relation is valid for which cases?What are some examples of cases in which it is not valid? Can this formula be used to find the magnetic moment of a uniformly charged non conducting sphere rotating with constant angular velocity?

Comment: The orbital magnetic moment has a classical derivation. This relation is classical and is valid, the quantum $\mu$ or $M$ has the same expresion as $g_L=1$ but can only be measured along one direction and is quantized. Any other angular momentum is not classical and this expression does not hold.